# What does mano-a-mano actually mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, vocabulary, slang

I know that expression comes from Spanish a it’s literal meaning is hand by hand. However, I often find some other meanings like:

> *fight; like a man to man; eye to eye*.

How common is this phrase in general? Is it appropriate in a more or less formal language? I understand that the meaning depends on the context. l’d like to understand what meaning is is the most frequently used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very much slang. It is most common in the Southern parts of the USA, where there are substantial Hispanic populations. It is like other slang borrowings:  "Hasta la vista",  "mi casa su casa", "No problemo"  and so on.  Like other slang expressions, it is not appropriate in a formal context.

Certainly, the fact it sounds like "man-at-man" has influenced how it is understood in English. In English, it is used to mean "close confrontation", or "head-to-head", which is rather different from its meaning in Spanish.

Answer (score 2):

“mano-a-mano” is not English, though people who live in areas with a significant Hispanic population may know and use it.

The direct translation would be fighting “hand to hand”, meaning with bare fists, also known as a “fistfight”.